# Is it inefficient to recursively descend my DOM in javascript vs. using document.getElementsByClassname?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am right now recursively descending my DOM in javascript looking for a specific (custom) attribute. This works, but I'm just curious if this is inefficient versus built in query functionality in JavaScript / JQuery.

```
function createTooltipsRecurse(elem) {
  if (!elem.getAttribute) return;
  if (elem.getAttribute('tooltip')) {
    $(elem).hover(
      function (event) {
        $('#tt').html(elem.getAttribute('tooltip'));
        $('#tt').css('left',(event.pageX + 10) + 'px');
        $('#tt').css('top',event.pageY + 'px');
        $('#tt').show();
      },
      function (event) {
        $('#tt').hide();
      });
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < elem.childNodes.length; i++) {
    createTooltipsRecurse(elem.childNodes[i]);
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I guess it comes down to how many elements are on the page.

Comment: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)  But in general, using the browser supplied functions like `getElementsByClassname` (or perhaps in this case `querySelectorAll`) _should_ be faster as they can apply implementation specific performance enhancements.  At the end of the day, you need to measure it in your target environment to see which is better for your needs.

Comment: Using DOM selectors is firstmost more declarative and easier to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now fully native (therefore faster) and with very convenient JQuery/CSS selectors:

```
document.querySelectorAll('*[your-attribute]');
```

This will return the list of the nodes with `your-attribute`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note that `querySelectorAll` only supports CSS selectors - jQuery (via sizzle) does extend the functionality a little, but does internally use QSA where possible.

Comment: This seems to be the solution, but I can't seem to get document.querySelectorAll (or querySelector) to work in my webbrowser - IE 11. The Exception is "Object doesn't support property or method querySelectorAll". I tried searching for that and found advice about marking the document with <DOCTYPE html> (which I already had). Do you have any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: Nevermind, I hadn't included <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" />. When I added that it worked!

Comment: Actually, this also fixed an issue I had with css and getting different results in different locations on the file system, so thank you twice!